# Go Get not Working for downloading HyperledgerFabric

Tags: git, go, ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am trying to run this sample app from the IBM Bluemix BlockChain Examples:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html#hellocc

I am running the following Command:
C:\goProjects>go get github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/tree/v0.5-developer-preview/core/chaincode/shim

The error I get is below.

```
package github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/tree/v0.5-developer-preview/core/chaincode/shim: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/tree/v0.5-developer-preview/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\github.com\hyperledger-archives\fabric\tree\v0.5-developer-preview\core\chaincode\shim (from $GOROOT)
        C:\goProjects\src\github.com\hyperledger-archives\fabric\tree\v0.5-developer-preview\core\chaincode\shim (from $GOPATH)
```

Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

`go get` doesn't allow you to pull a specific branch of a library.

You can pull the master with:

`go get -d github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/core/chaincode/shim`

What you're looking for is probably using the **vendoring** folder.

Some resources on how to use it, and what it is, are here:

- [A post on reddit on how to use Vendoring](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/4c0up7/how_to_use_go_vendoring/d1f7z3q/)
- [A post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188904/2728768)
- [A blog post about the `govendor` tool](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/)

Remember that vendoring has been introduced as experimental with Go 1.5, accepted in 1.6, and is default in 1.7 at the time we're writing, therefore in general if your build tool finds the same library in the `vendor` folder, it will use that one (in your case you can pull the specific version of the code you need)

You can do this manually, or using one of the [package management tools available.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools#go15vendorexperiment)

Comment: To get it working, he could just manually check it out to $GOPATH/hyperledger-archived/fabric

Comment: Yes, that's an option, and then he can switch to the proper branch with `git branch v0.5-developer-preview`

Answer (score 0):

We are in the process of correcting the documentation. You can use

> get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim

or

> go get github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/core/chaincode/shim

which fixes the problem.