# Is it possible to get the git tag with "go get"?

Tags: git, go

I would like to add a `--version` option to my Go binary, [c2go](https://github.com/elliotchance/c2go).

I know traditionally this would be hardcoded into the binary but since it's alpha quality software and it's being updated very often I'd like to capture the version when the `go get` builds the executable (from the git tag).

Is this possible?

Comment: i am not very clear about the problem, see if this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/42766877/3435777

Comment: `gopkg.in` is used as a redirect service to allow `go get` to fetch a specific version, but I want to always get the HEAD, but capture the git tag when `go build` runs so it can automatically encode the version into the app without me having to update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do "go get" on a specific tag of a github repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188499/how-to-do-go-get-on-a-specific-tag-of-a-github-repository)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question is when you want to request a specific version. I want the latest version, but when it builds it uses the fetched version.

Answer (score 2):

This does not exactly answer your question, but the way I solved a similar need is the following.

In my `main` package, I define the following variables:

```
var (
    buildInfo  string
    buildStamp = "No BuildStamp provided"
    gitHash    = "No GitHash provided"
    version    = "No Version provided"
)
```

and in my `main` function, I execute the following code:

```
if buildInfo != "" {
    parts := strings.Split(buildInfo, "|")
    if len(parts) >= 3 {
        buildStamp = parts[0]
        gitHash = parts[1]
        version = parts[2]
    }
}
```

I then build my application with the following `bash` (Linux) shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "${0%/*}"

buildInfo="`date -u '+%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'`|`git describe --always --long`|`git tag | tail -1`"
go build -ldflags "-X main.buildInfo=${buildInfo} -s -w" ./cmd/...
```

You will need to adjust the script for Windows and MacOS.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. (Note that go get supports other SCM than git too).