# How to point Go module dependency in go.mod to a latest commit in a repo?

Tags: git, go, module

Starting with v1.11 Go added support for modules. Commands

```bash
go mod init <package name>
go build
```

would generate `go.mod` and `go.sum` files that contain all found versions for the package dependencies. If a module does not have any releases, the latest commit of that module is used. If a module does have releases, the latest one is picked as a dependency.

However sometimes I would need functionality that is not in a published release yet, but from a commit made after that release. How do I set `go.mod` to point not to a release of a module, but to a specific commit in the module's repository? It looks like I can do it by hand in `go.mod` with

```golang
module /my/module
    
require (
    ...
    github.com/someone/some_module v0.0.0-20181121201909-af044c0995fe
    ...
)
```

where `v0.0.0` does not correspond to the last published release tag, `20181121201909` would be a commit timestamp and `af044c0995fe` would be the commit hash? Should such information to be found and entered by hand, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Just 'go get' at the commit hash you want:

```
go get github.com/someone/some_module@af044c0995fe
```

'go get' will correctly update the dependency files (go.mod, go.sum).

More information: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies

Comment: In case getting error "**unknown revision**" or "**invalid version**" - Make sure that you did not specify **hash of PR** (pull request). Even a merged PR might be wrong. Look for the commit hash in the repo under `/commits`, but not under `/pulls`. See more info here: [golang/go#31191](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31191) explicitly filters out these kind of commits.

Comment: the OP askes how to add it to go.mod file , not how to do a `go get`

Comment: @Nulik `go get` is the correct way to update/add-to `go.mod` in the way the OP asked.

Comment: Note that you can also specify a branch or tag name instead of a commit hash.

Comment: @cambraca you cant use the branch name if it's past v1 or you will get `invalid version: go.mod has post-v1 module path`

Comment: thanks heaps. Cleaning cache and go mod tidy did not help much before that 

Comment: Never worked in my case

Answer (score 187):

In addition the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682399/11210494) from Everton on using `go get github.com/someone/some_module@af044c0995fe` to get a specific commit, you can also use branch names such as:

- `go get github.com/someone/some_module@master`
- `go get github.com/someone/some_module@dev_branch`

Those examples get the latest commit on the corresponding branch.

It will still be recorded as a [pseudo-version](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions) in your `go.mod` file, such as `v0.0.0-20171006230638-a6e239ea1c69`. (This helps provide a simple total ordering across all versions based on standard [semver](https://semver.org) ordering).

Comment: thanks for the pseudo-version explanation.
i was trying to do a `replace` to use a temporary fork of some dependency, but could not find a way to make that replacement to point to  some commit. Had to create a version tag and specify it like this `replace github.com/original/somelib => github.com/fork/somelib v1.2.3`, which is a bit too much when i just want to quickly test stuff.  

`replace github.com/original/somelib => github.com/fork/somelib@commithash` and 
`replace github.com/original/somelib => github.com/fork/somelib commithash` do not work

Comment: 1. push your code to `github.com/fork/somelib` @ `dev` branch  2. modify your  go.mod file, add a line `replace github.com/original/somelib => github.com/fork/somelib dev`  3. execute `go mod tidy` command.  After done these, go will auto replace the `dev` in go.mod to a suitiable pseudo-version.

Comment: you cant use the branch name if it's past v1 or you will get `invalid version: go.mod has post-v1 module path`

Comment: The @dev_branch doesn't work if the branch name contains slashes.

Comment: Like mentioned by @hookenz, branch with slashes don't work, in those case use the full commit + `go mod tidy`:  `... => github.com/<org>/<name> b5906304132ae4379efd349040df095e555ba5b7` of said branch

Answer (score 36):

If you want to temporarily substitute a dependency to a local directory (for example if you work on 2 modules sumultaneously) you can add `replace` statement at the end of `go.mod` file:

```
module example.com/mypkg

go 1.15

require (
  gitlab.com/someone/a_package v0.14.2
)

replace gitlab.com/someone/a_package => ../my_forks/a_package
```

Comment: The question is asking about latest commit in a remote repo, not a local checked-out state.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to test a project with a remote module branch because I didn´t know it was possible to target a local directory.

Answer (score 29):

I have been banging my head for some time that how it works for everyone and I am not able to run it. For me, I had to commit to master branch then only I was able to get it.

For go get to work with specific branch, commit id or tag, you need to enable a flag for go module by running below command

> go env -w GO111MODULE=on

after this we will be able to do

```
go get repo@branchname
go get repo@tag
go get repo@commithash
```

Answer (score 23):

Also if you put the word latest in place of the tag in the go.mod file it will get changed to the latest tag the modules.

For example:

```
module /my/module

require (
...
github.com/someone/some_module latest
...
)
```

will become

```
module /my/module

require (
...
github.com/someone/some_module v2.0.39
...
)
```

after running `go mod tidy`

Comment: That's probably the easiest!

Answer (score 15):

- Download source from branch
  `go get your-repo@branch-name`
  read output with go module version to be added to `require` or `replace`:

  *go: downloading github.com/your-repo v1.2.3-0.20210609123456-123123123*
- Later this version can be found as output string of the following command
  `go list -m -json your-repo@branch-name | jq '.|"\(.Path) \(.Version)"'`
- If `jq` is not installed on your PC - manually combine `Path` and `Version` values of result from: 
  `go list -m -json your-repo@branch-name`
   separated by space:
  *your-repository v1.2.3-0.20210609123456-123123123*

Comment: I got the following error: `malformed module path "foo/bar": missing dot in first path element` for the command: `go list -m -json foo/bar@main`

Comment: @Dentrax Try something like `go list -m -json github.com/foo/bar@main`