# go get -u github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo starts throwing error all of a sudden

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get

When I run `go get -u github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo`

till yesterday I had no issues. Specifically with `fsnotify` the output was like below

```
00:52:08 go: downloading gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1 v1.4.7
00:52:08 go: extracting gopkg.in/tomb.v1 v1.0.0-20141024135613-dd632973f1e7
00:52:08 go: extracting gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1 v1.4.7
```

Now I see this error while executing same command

```
11:50:39 go: gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1@v1.4.8: go.mod has non-....v1 module path "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify" at revision v1.4.8
11:50:39 go get: error loading module requirements
```

What might have gone wrong here

Comment: This link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682247/how-to-point-go-module-dependency-in-go-mod-to-a-latest-commit-in-a-repo` might be help. there is an update in your go package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some module in the transitive dependencies of `github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo` added a requirement on some version of `gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1`, which resolves to the repository hosted at `github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify`.

However, the `go.mod` file in that repository declares its canonical import path to be `github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify`, not `gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1`.

If you are using Go 1.14, the rest of the error message (which seems to be truncated) should tell you exactly which dependency is using the non-canonical path. The long-term fix is to move that dependency over to the canonical path and upgrade your other dependencies such that `gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1` is no longer required.