# How can I track down a function return mismatch in Go?

Tags: go

How can I track down a function return mismatch in Golang? In two different build environments I am seeing a difference. Both cases should be Visual Studio Code remote to a Linux box, using Go 1.12 in module mode. The broken case is where I am driving the build using the Golang:1.12 Docker image. Below is simplified from where I'm seeing the problem.

So for this sample, derived from https://github.com/satori/go.uuid:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

func main() {
    // or error handling
    u2, err := uuid.NewV4()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Something went wrong: %s", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("UUIDv4: %s\n", u2)
}
```

The unexpected build error is:

```
./main.go:11:5 assignment mismatch: 2 variables but uuid.NewV4() returns 1 values
```

In the environment where I encounter this problem, in Visual Studio Code when I hover with mouse over the call to uuid.NewV4() I see:

```
func uuid.NewV4() (uuid.UUID, error)

uuid.NewV4 on pkg.go.dev

NewV4 returns random generated UUID.
```

and hover over uuid shows:

```
package uuid ("github.com/satori/go.uuid")

uuid on pkg.go.dev
```

I may switch to a different uuid package to work around this -- but I want to understand better how to figure this out.

Comment: Use Go modules to pin the version of go.uuid.

Comment: @Volker thanks -- I had it on 1.2.0 in go.mod, now forced to 1.2.1, seems to work as I had expected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess problem is in different `github.com/satori/go.uuid` module versions. You can see, that `NewV4` function signature was updated to `NewV4() (uuid.UUID, error)` in [latest version `v1.2.0`](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/blob/d91630c8510268e75203009fe7daf2b8e1d60c45/generator.go#L68). Before that it [was `func NewV4() UUID`](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/blob/v1.1.0/uuid.go#L462)

Then resolve to a specific version as in this question:

[How to point Go module dependency in go.mod to a latest commit in a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682247/how-to-point-go-module-dependency-in-go-mod-to-a-latest-commit-in-a-repo)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how VSCode ( guess via gopls) picks the function help information it displays?

Comment: @learning2learn My guess is gopls, yes. But really, i don't know about VSCode internals(and don't use it) ;)