# How to import a library with a special branch in Go

Tags: git, go, import, module

I am new for Go, and I am working on the project which need importing internal library.
I can use go get to import it, and it works very well.
So I noticed that running go get, it will import the master branch.
However, I have a special case, that I need to import a dev branch instead of master branch.
After doing some research, I tried go get libraryUrl@branchName, and it does not work for me.
Any idea how to do it?
Here is my go mod info

```
module projectName
go 1.15
require(
     github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0
     internal libraryURL v0.01
)
```

Thank you for the help.
And let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found out why it does not work for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank to @blackgreen, who give me a link regarding this problem.
I post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682247/how-to-point-go-module-dependency-in-go-mod-to-a-latest-commit-in-a-repo) for someone who met the same problem as me.
The conclusion is if go get libraryUrl@branchName doesn't work for you, set up the  go env -w GO111MODULE=on. Then it shall work.