# Best practice to work on two github go projects

Tags: go

I am working on two github based golang projects where one project is dependent on other.

Let say I have project A (github.com/A) depending on project B (github.com/B). So as of now, I am making changes to project B, pushing the code, and executing `go get github.com/B` in project A, to fetch the latest code of project B.

This procedure is time consuming and also doesn't sound right to me. I have thought the changing files of project B at GO_PATH location, but seems downloaded projects at GO_PATH are read only.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Always require the latest version of a dependency in go.mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68273365/always-require-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency-in-go-mod)

Comment: You will have to automate it using a small script. I would suggest using makefile and add a command to go get the latest version of your dependency, so when you do say `make build` it gets updated each time before building.

Comment: @Jay Agreed, might need either `Makefile` or something like `Bazel`.

Comment: There is a better way: the "replace" directive in go.mod, you would replace github.com/B to the path on the local filesystem of the checked out B. This obviously only during development. See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Leverage golang workspaces

If your golang version is 1.18+ you can leverage the workspaces feature in order  to improve your development experience.

Let's use your examples, so we have `github.com/A` which depends on `github.com/B`.

1. Make sure they are in the same parent folder and let's assume that the name of that folder is `workspace`
2. `cd` in `workspace`, then `go mod init ./A && go work use ./B`
3. In the `workspace` run `go run github.com/A`

The result would be that in your local development environment you will use always your local version of `github.com/B`, so no need for remote syncing.

If you are using previous version of go, I think your best bet is to do some scripting in order to automate this process