# What does the Go Mod require mean

Tags: go, go-modules

Related to [How to point Go module dependency in go.mod to a latest commit in a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682247/how-to-point-go-module-dependency-in-go-mod-to-a-latest-commit-in-a-repo)

I have the following require in go.mod file

```
require (
    github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.16.5
    github.com/onsi/gomega v1.18.1
    k8s.io/api v0.24.2
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.24.2
    k8s.io/client-go v0.24.2
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.12.2
    sigs.k8s.io/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern v0.11.20220513-0.20220602225619-fe5be9431eae // Added for status (run go mod tidy)

)
```

The last one I am not able to understand. The repo is https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern
It does NOT have a tag named `v0.11.20220513` (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern/tags)
It has a commit tag `fe5be9431eae`

Anyone has an idea how to go to the commit referred to by `v0.11.20220513-0.20220602225619-fe5be9431eae` and what does each part mean?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern/commit/fe5be9431eae158f86f9de23000a9a2ec06745fc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://go.dev/ref/mod#pseudo-versions:

> A pseudo-version is a *specially formatted* **pre-release version** that
> encodes information about a specific revision in a version control
> repository. For example, `v0.0.0-20191109021931-daa7c04131f5` is a
> pseudo-version.

So, once you read the full pseudo-versions section that's linked above, you'll find out that the version
`v0.11.20220513-0.20220602225619-fe5be9431eae` is composed of the following three parts:

1. `v0.11.20220513`: the base version [v0.11.20220512](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern/releases/tag/v0.11.20220512)+1.

   > `vX.Y.(Z+1)-0.yyyymmddhhmmss-abcdefabcdef` is used when the base version
   > is a release version like vX.Y.Z. For example, if the base version is
   > v1.2.3, a pseudo-version might be
   > v1.2.4-0.20191109021931-daa7c04131f5.
2. `0.20220602225619`: is the timestamp `0.yyyymmddhhmmss`.

   > A timestamp (yyyymmddhhmmss), which is the UTC time the revision was created. In Git, this is the commit time, not the author time.
3. `fe5be9431eae`: is the [commit hash](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern/commit/fe5be9431eae).

   > A revision identifier (abcdefabcdef), which is a 12-character prefix of the commit hash, or in Subversion, a zero-padded revision number.

Answer (score 1):

As [pseudo-version](https://go.dev/ref/mod#pseudo-versions) explains, the third part of this is a 12-character prefix of the commit hash. so you can go to the commit on the repo directly by browsing `<repo-path>/commit/<commit-prefix>`.

In your case, it is [`https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern/commit/fe5be9431eae`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder-declarative-pattern/commit/fe5be9431eae)