# How to get the specified version(tag) of package by using go get?

Tags: go

How to get the specified version(tag) of package by using go get?

`go get github.com/owner/repo`

In the above command, how to specify version or tag of the package.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855081/how-do-i-import-a-specific-version-of-a-package-using-go-get) is related to your question.

Comment: Related, read this initiative: [Gophers, please tag your releases](http://dave.cheney.net/2016/06/24/gophers-please-tag-your-releases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Volker's correct, but here's a way to use a particular version in your project:

```
go get github.com/sirupsen/logrus
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus
git checkout v0.9.0
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/YOU/PROJECT
govendor add github.com/sirupsen/logrus  # or similar
```

Comment: Don't forget to `go install ./...` after `git checkout` if the module contains tools like `protoc`