# How to get another branch instead of default branch with go get

Tags: git, github, go

I have 2 repositories. Let say them repo_a and repo_b. I imported repo_a in repo_b

When I ran go get, it will get repo_a master branch.
Is there any way to get develop branch using go get or another command from repo_b?

I do not want to git pull on each specific package (in this case repo_a)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import a specific version of a package using go get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855081/how-do-i-import-a-specific-version-of-a-package-using-go-get)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Starting with Go 1.11, this is possible when using [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules). When installing a dependency for a Go module, you can specify a [module query](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_queries) which may contain a branch or tag name:

```
$ go get <path-to-repo>@<branch>
```

Comment: With go 1.13 u can encounter an error when trying to get a branch, the error end with "invalid version: unknown revision XXX".

You can workaround that by using the commit hash instead of the branch name.

Comment: [Only if your branch name contains a slash](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32955), then you will get an error on Go 1.13. The workaround is you to use the commit SHA1 instead of the branch name.

Comment: The <path-to-repo>@<commit> does not work in gerrit if the commit is outside the main branch.

Answer (score 20):

#### Stable HEAD philosophy

**It is not possible with pure `go get`.**

> Go takes the most minimal and pragmatic approach of any package manager. There is no such thing as multiple versions of a Go package.

But this is not as bad as it seems at the first view because there exists a philosophy behind this behavior.

> As a package author, you must adhere to the stable HEAD philosophy. Your default branch must always be the stable, released version of your package. You must do work in feature branches and only merge when ready to release.

This approach is forced by `go get` limitations and it should be treated like Python indentations - it is kind of philosophy forced by language design.

#### Development approaches

If you want to fork something or try new features you can clone repo then switch to a desired branch and do `go build`. This way shouldn't go to production.

```
git clone <repo name>
cd <repo name>
git checkout <branch name>
go build
```

Also you can use third party package management tools. But most of them support tags and revisions, not branches (since it is implied that you don't need to install feature branch).

[gpm](https://github.com/pote/gpm):

> You can specify packages with the   format, where version can be a revision number (a git/bazaar/mercurial/svn revision hash) or a tag.

Comment: In response to "most of them support tags and revisions, not branches," one that does seem to support branches is Glide, according to [their versioning doc](https://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versions/).

Answer (score 16):

you can use `gopkg.in`, it will redirect to github.

There are two URL patterns supported:

```
gopkg.in/pkg.v3      → github.com/go-pkg/pkg (branch/tag v3, v3.N, or v3.N.M)
gopkg.in/user/pkg.v3 → github.com/user/pkg   (branch/tag v3, v3.N, or v3.N.M)
```

`go get gopkg.in/pkg.v3` means `go get github.com/go-pkg/pkg`, but is branch or tag `v3.*`.

for more details, see [here](http://labix.org/gopkg.in)