# importing non-master go branch in another go repo

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules

I have a service called at `github.com/me/service` and I import this in a worker `github.com/me/worker`. I pushed a branch to the service, say `dev_branch` and when I do:

```
go get github.com/me/service@commit_sha // or @dev_branch - I tried both
```

in the worker, it complains:

```
go: github.com/me/service@commit_sha (v1.127.1-0.20240329155249-788847162b0f) requires github.com/me/service/gen-go/models@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: 
github.com/me/service/gen-go/models@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

which makes me confused. Here, `v1.127.1-0.20240329155249-788847162b0f` and `v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000` are actual numbers I got (currently the master in the service is at `v1.127.0`). In the service's `go.mod` file, I do see:

```
module github.com/me/service
...

require (
...
github.com/me/service/gen-go/models@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
...
)
```

and it has been this way since forever and working just fine. What am I missing here ? I did go through some questions here at SOF such as [how get another branch instead of default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761820/how-to-get-another-branch-instead-of-default-branch-with-go-get) and the subsequent ones that are linked, but none seems to solve my issue.