# `go get` : unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: go, module

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version
v1.12
```

The module [yiigo](https://github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo) has tag `v3.0.0`, but when I run `go get github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo`, it gets the `v2.1.0` and when I run `go get github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo@v3.0.0`, it shows: `go get github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo@v3.0.0: unexpected end of JSON input`

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue seems to be that the v3.0.0 version of `iiinsomnia/yiigo` is missing the required `/v3` at the end of the `module` line in its `go.mod` file:

https://github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo/blob/v3.0.0/go.mod#L1

```
module github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo    <<<< wrong, missing required /v3 at end

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.1-0.20190217072658-972a708cf979
    ...
```

That has since been corrected.

Because it is now a proper v3 module, the `go get` command should include a `/v3` before the `@`:

```
module github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo/v3@v3.2.2
```

From the [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#semantic-import-versioning) wiki:

> If the module is version v2 or higher, the major version of the module *must* be included as a /vN at the end of the module paths used in go.mod files (e.g., `module github.com/my/mod/v2`, `require github.com/my/mod/v2 v2.0.0`) and in the package import path (e.g., `import "github.com/my/mod/v2/mypkg"`).

Also, it looks like a related issue was opened, with the theory being that the odd "unexpected end of JSON input" error might have come from some proxy:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30494

Answer (score -1):

A way I've accomplished this in the past is by using `git tags`- for your case this should work fine.

Steps:

1. `go get -u github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo`
2. `cd ~/go/src/github.com/iiinsomnia/yiigo`
3. `git tag`
4. *locate tag release version you'd like to install within list*
5. `git checkout v3.0.0`
6. `go install`

This will overwrite the package previously installed in your GOPATH with a new one for the specific tag version you have checked out.

*Note: there is likely a better way to do this since the release of go modules.*

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855081/how-do-i-import-a-specific-version-of-a-package-using-go-get/36403089) related post also provides alternative solutions on how to retrieve a specific version of a project's source code that may lend some help.