# Terraform Provider-specify version of SDK to pull / Cannot use validation.StringInSlice type schema.SchemaValidateFunc as type SchemaValidateDiagFunc

Tags: go, terraform, terraform0.12+

Due to [this problem](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/534) it looks like for providers you have to get a current version of the SDK (2.4.4 at time of post). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855081/how-do-i-import-a-specific-version-of-a-package-using-go-get) has a lot of info on how to import a specific version of a package but surely every single provider writer isn't manually pulling the most recent version of the SDK (or are they)?

I'm new to Go/Terraform so maybe I'm missing something obvious but the providers I've found (including the official example) have something like:

```
import(
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/diag"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/validation"
)
```

The current version is not 2 - it is `2.4.4`. Now I know those are local paths but what confuses me is when I run something like `go get` it goes and pulls those down for me. I tried doing:

```
"github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2.4.4/helper/schema"
```

but `go get` very much doesn't like that. How is `go get` finding those package versions? Is there an import syntax that just gets me the latest build or allows me more granularity? I haven't found a good way to tell what version of the SDK I have after running `go get` but based on this error message:

[image: Error]

it looks like I have 2.0 because that error is, as I understand it, fixed in newer versions of the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The behavior is controlled by the [go.mod](https://golangbyexample.com/go-mod-sum-module/) file.

In there you'll find:

```
require (
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk v1.14.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.0.1
```

As mentioned by @JimB the v2 is the [major version](https://golang.org/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes) for the plugin. `v2.0.1` are GitHub tags. Changing this to `v2.4.4` obtains the desired behavior.

Comment: Major version suffixes are covered in any of the module documentation, https://golang.org/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes

Comment: Thank you! I updated the answer to reflect that.